# NaturalId, how it works?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, composite-primary-key

I´m having a problem with nativeid and i don´t know if i am doing right.

I have a class called Aircraft that has an generated id. But its native id is the serial number(Integer) and Model( a custom class) like below:

```
public class Aircraft{

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="COD_NS_AENV")
@Column(name="COD_NS")
private Integer id;
@Column(name="NUM_IDENT_NS_AENV")
@NaturalId
private Integer serialNumber;
@ManyToOne
@NaturalId
private Model model;

.
.
.
}
```

I load this class from an XML and save into the database, like this:

```
.
.
.
Aircraft aircraft= (Aircraft)xstream.fromXML(reader);
Session session =  HibernateUtil.openSession();
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

session.saveOrUpdate(aircraft.getModelo());
session.saveOrUpdate(aircraft);
t.commit();
session.close();
```

It works fine for insert,but my problem is when I execute this code again with the same information, Hibernate inserts another aircraft. I want that Hibernate only updates the current registry.

I overrided the method equals() to test the serialNumber and Model attributes but it is never called.

I don´t know how to make Hibernate understand that an object with serialNumber and model are the NativeId.

Thanks in advance!

Alexandre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely Hibernate just uses `@Id` property and generates new value every time. That happens because you read your object from XML and id is not in XML, I assume. I don't think natural id will coexist well with surrogate autogenerated id. And for `saveOrUpdate` Hibernate will just look at `id` to determine if object is new.

Here is more details on [Hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=975527&view=previous).

Comment: I thought hibernate would look the ids defined by @NaturalID. Where can i use NaturalId? is there an useful excample?

Comment: Then why did you define `@Id`? It surely takes precedence.

Comment: I defined id because I don´t want to create a composite-id. Only the insert/update would look to the NaturalId

Comment: Well, apparently it does not work. I don't think NaturalId is a popular concept and you may be better off with composite id.

Comment: If hibernate use the method equals of my object i think it would work.

Comment: Just in case someone comes here looking for a solution, with hibernate 4.1 release, hibernate now has better support for `@NaturalId`. Look [here](http://relation.to/Bloggers/41FeatureLoadingByNaturalId).